# Artisan error "error":{"type":"PDOException","message":"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory","file":

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, command-line-interface, laravel-artisan

Just tried to run artisan dump-autoload and came accross this:

```
{"error":{"type":"PDOException","message":"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory","file":"\/Applications\/MAMP\/htdocs\/blog\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Database\/Connectors\/Connector.php","line":47}}
```

Never seen that before and there is nothing I can think of that I have changed regarding the DB. For the record, all other Database functions are working fine.

EDIT: Simply running:

```
php artisan
```

also gives the same error.

Comment: Do other artisan commands work? Are you sure artisan is running under the right "environment"? Perhaps you set up your db connections in "local" and artisan is running under production, for example.

Comment: Nope, `php artisan` return the same error. Ill take a look into that, it was working couple of days ago however

Comment: Try `php artisan dump-autoload --env=whatever-env-you-have-db-setup`. Also, did you recently upgrade to Laravel 5?

Comment: Still on 4.2, and have not yet set up any environments on this Laravel project.

Comment: So where did you put your db connection settings? Just in 'app/config/database.php'?

Answer (score 4):

Change the host name in your database config file `app/config/database.php` from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Laravel on MAMP for MAC, you can fix it like this:

Edit database.php and add the following line inside 'mysql' connection:

'unix_socket' => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',

Example:

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'unix_socket' => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```